# C++ Policy Based Design With Variable Type Return Value

Tags: c++, templates

I want to used Policy Based Design to have the return type of a host class change based on the policies I'm using. Here is an example:

```
class IntPolicy {
public:
    int doIntPolicy(double anInput) {
        return static_cast<int>(anInput);
    }
};

class DoublePolicy {
public:
    double doDoublePolicy(int anInput) {
        return static_cast<double>(anInput);
    }
};

template<typename IntPolicyType, typename DoublePolicyType>
class SimpleHost {

private:
    IntPolicyType _intPolicy;
    DoublePolicyType _doublePolicy;

public:

    template<typename InputType>
    auto doHost(InputType input) -> decltype(_doublePolicy.doDoublePolicy(_intPolicy.doIntPolicy(input))) {
        auto aVar =  _intPolicy.doIntPolicy(input);
        return _doublePolicy.doDoublePolicy(aVar);
    }


};
```

Here is how I'd use the host class and policies:

```
typedef SimpleHost<IntPolicy, DoublePolicy> Host;
Host host;
auto theOutput = host.doHost(5);
```

While this compiles and works, notice that I must essentially put the body of the doHost method inside the decltype function so that the compiler can deduce the trailing return. If the body of the doHost function was large then this would look incredibly ugly. Is there any way I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like how it looks then probably try define?

```
#define RECURSE_POLICY(E) policy2.doPolicy(policy1.doPolicy(E)) 
template<typename InputType>
auto doHost(InputType input) -> decltype(RECURSE_POLICY(input)) {
    return RECURSE_POLICY(input);
}
```

Having said that, something doesn't look right that you have to call doPolicy twice. Maybe you can refactor it out.

Comment: Sorry for naming the methods of both the Int and Double policies "doPolicy". They are indeed two different policies which are intended to be orthogonal. Please see the updated names.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Extending the template

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class IntPolicy {
public:
    int doIntPolicy(double anInput=NULL) {
        if(!NULL)
        {
            return static_cast<int>(anInput);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
};

class DoublePolicy {
public:
    double doDoublePolicy(int anInput=NULL) {
        if(!NULL)
        {
            return static_cast<double>(anInput);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

};



template<typename IntPolicyType, typename DoublePolicyType,
    class __Type >
class SimpleHost {

private:
    IntPolicyType _intPolicy;
    DoublePolicyType _doublePolicy;

public:

    template<typename InputType>
    auto doHost(InputType input) -> __Type {
        auto aVar =  _intPolicy.doIntPolicy(input);
        return _doublePolicy.doDoublePolicy(aVar);
    }



};

int main()
{
    IntPolicy foo;
    DoublePolicy bar;
    typedef SimpleHost<IntPolicy, DoublePolicy, 
        decltype(bar.doDoublePolicy(foo.doIntPolicy()))> Host;
    Host host;
    auto theOutput = host.doHost(5);

    return 0;
}
```

2.- The simplest way would be to rename the impl, if you are using an external library you could consider Wrapping it for this purpose

```
class IntPolicy {
public:
    int doPolicy(double anInput) {
        return static_cast<int>(anInput);
    }
};

class DoublePolicy {
public:
    double doPolicy(int anInput) {
        return static_cast<double>(anInput);
    }

};



template<typename IntPolicyType, typename DoublePolicyType>
class SimpleHost {

private:
    IntPolicyType _intPolicy;
    DoublePolicyType _doublePolicy;

public:

    template<typename InputType>
    auto doHost(InputType input) -> decltype(_doublePolicy.doPolicy(_intPolicy.doPolicy(input))) 
    {
        auto aVar =  IntPolicyType.doPolicy(input);
        return DoublePolicyType.doPolicy(aVar);
    }
```

But to really help you, we need the specific functions you are trying to call, I mean I feel like this is a mess already.